# An object can outlive another ...What does it mean?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am studying design patterns. 
 In the UML description aggregation its defined so : A has B , and B can outlive A.
 Element to describe that is :

A<>------B   (where the funny arrows, should be a diamond)

I simply do not understand the concept of "***OUTLIVE***" even if I understand that B type is in A under the form of a field (property...etc).

What do they mean with this "outlive" ?? In which case B can outlive A ?

Comment: Perhaps there is another reference to B somewhere, such that even if A is destroyed, B is still in memory.

Comment: Yes but then, this is a little bit irelevant because we are speaking about managed language (C#). You would have to have a pointer to access the B type.

Comment: You just need a reference somewhere, not necessarily a pointer. See my answer below for an illustration.

Comment: Example: http://ideone.com/rT24vA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that B is/could be referenced from outside A in some way.

It's easier to get in contrast with Composition, where B is solely 'owned' by A and then when A becomes unreachable, B automatically becomes garbage too.

So lifetime is used here to define visibility/scope. A little backward reasoning.

Comment: Exactly . I think that also. On the other examples I used a destructor for the classes to see if object = null; will acctually delete my object and execute what the destructor had. IT doesn't !!! It does that only at the end of my thread.(Where all others are anyway collected!!)So your point of view is the correct one! It is backward!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code. A requires a B to instantiate, but destroying A does not destroy B.

When class C creates a new A, it gives it a reference to the B it already has. Now, even if A is destroyed, goes out of scope, etc. B is still 'alive.'

```
class A
{
    private B b;

    public A(B bType)
    {
        this.b = bType;
    }
}

class B
{ 
}

class C
{
    private B b = new B();

    private A a;

    public C()
    {
        a = new A(b);
        a = null; // b is still alive
    }
}
```